# Safely Dir.glob or File.read with user-supplied path

Tags: ruby, security

Let's say I am making a webserver which reads files from my system.

I have a root directory, say `~/Public` and users can request any file in there (or in subfolders.

So I'd do something like `File.read(File.join(RootDir, params[:path]))` and then send that onward to the user.

The problem is there's a clear security risk here. If the user gives a path like `"../../secret_file"`, they have left my `~/Public` folder and can read pretty much anything from my system - obviously, a bad thing.

I'm thinking about how I can do this safely.

The easiest thing is to do just strip out `".."` from any user-supplied paths. Would this suffice or is it still risky?

The other option is to use Nginx or some other static server which already has this functionality built in. But I guess, they are doing the same preventative measure I need to here, so why can't I just do it myself?

Comment: I would retrieve the file's absolute pathname via [`realpath`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/File.html#realpath-method) and check if it starts with the (absolute) root directory.